# The oracle sql developer 19.2.1 doesn't show the connection name in the login prompt. Is there any way to bring that back in this version?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

The oracle sql developer 19.2.1 doesn't show the connection name in the login prompt. Is there any way to bring that back in this version?
If not, in this version is it possible to launch the sql developer and pass username password and instance as parameter via command line?

Comment: I'm about to make you very happy. Blog post and full answer coming up soon but here's the details/code for cli launching SQLDev with a connection https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/sqldeveloper/extension/java/ConnectionHelper

Comment: Thank you so much for this... Will try this out!!!!

Comment: @thatjeffsmith while doing the setup and running the ant _deploy, it is giving few compile errors wrt the exampleresources.java.. I have set ant up and the commands seems to be working and I have changed the path in the /sqldeveloper/build.properties as well.. Is there anything else to be done??

Comment: Any idea on the steps to be done?

Comment: Share the compile errors back as issues on the github page and the dev can take a look